# Most popular content content modules in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

What's the best way to do most popular content in Drupal 7?

I've been using the [Most Popular](http://www.drupal.org/project/mostpopular) module because I haven't been able to find anything else, but that only has ~750 odd users spread between the D6 and D7 versions. Surely popular content is a fairly-common requirement? That leads me to believe there's a better maintained (and hopefully less buggy) module that does the exact same thing, just it has an obscure name and I can't find it via Google. If so, what is it?

(If you're going to [crucify me for asking for an alternative module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49270/d7-conditional-field-option#comment50971_49270), note that I've contributed several issues and a documentation patch for Most Popular, and have volunteered to contribute code patches. However, there hasn't been a single commit on that module in ~6 months.)

Thank you!

Comment: Almost all functionality of this module you can implement using Views + modules that calculate desired statistics.

Comment: @Eugene -- Any suggestions for the latter beyond Drupal's core statistics module?

Comment: What exact statistics do you need?

Comment: @EugeneFidelin -- Mainly just pageviews; I'm trying to find the most-viewed content of the last, say, 6 months.

Comment: For this purpose use Radioactivity module as it is described here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/21075/7313

Comment: Radioactivity is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all functionality of this module you can implement using Views + [Radioactivity](http://drupal.org/project/radioactivity) module as it is described here [drupal.stackexchange.com/a/21075/7313](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/21075/7313)

Comment: Wow, that module is rad -- I like how they keep the metaphor running throughout (Half-life, cut-off, etc.). Thanks!